# Librosa read MP3 audio from URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, librosa

I am trying to read Mp3 audio from URL using Librosa. I understand that Librosa first uses PySoundFile to load the audio and if that fails it then uses audioread.

I have the following code so far:

```
import librosa
import io
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://sneezoramafunction.blob.core.windows.net/usersounds/00bd9b8c914947d48724fd7e0c88041b.mp3"

data, samplerate = librosa.load(io.BytesIO(urlopen(url).read()))
```

But this gives me the following error:

> RuntimeError: Error opening <_io.BytesIO object at 0x1c234747d0>: File
> contains data in an unknown format.

Additionally, I would be deploying this on Azure ML service and would not have any local storage available.

Thank you all for any help/advice

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Librosa can take an object of type BytesIO and process it by itself. You may need to save it locally (wav/mp3) and then load using Librosa.

```
z = io.BytesIO(urlopen(url).read())
import pathlib
pathlib.Path(('/home/<name>/sneeze.wav').write_bytes(z.getbuffer())
data, sr = librosa.load('/home/<name>/sneeze.wav')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I should have mentioned that I would be deploying this on Azure ML service and would not have any local storage available. I would add this to the question. 

Comment: hello, Singhal2, I'm working on a audio problem using librosa and I was wondering what technique you're using to deploy to Azure ML service. care to share some pointers?

Answer (score 2):

librosa uses `soundfile` and `audioread` to load audio files. Note that `soundfile` does not currently support `MP3`, which will cause `librosa` to fall back on the `audioread` library.

Answer (score 0):

https://librosa.org/doc/main/ioformats.html

```
import soundfile as sf
import io

from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/librosa/librosa/master/tests/data/test1_44100.wav"

data, samplerate = sf.read(io.BytesIO(urlopen(url).read()))
```